# Change \ttfamily font for entire document

Tags: fonts, typewriter

I'd like to change the teletype (`\ttfamily`) font that I'm using in my document. (I'm using the `scrartcl` class.) I've searched on stackexchange and Google, but all I can find are answers to how to change the base font to teletype.

How can I change just the teletype font for my document?

Comment: What do you want to use instead? For example, to make it equal to the normal font `\renewcommand{\ttfamily}{\rmfamily}`

Comment: I still want to use a teletype font, just one that also has bold.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

LaTeX remembers the default font family for `\ttfamily` in macro `\ttdefault`.
The default for `\ttdefault` in LaTeX (and KOMA-Script) without any other font packages is `cmtt` and addresses the teletype font of the Computer Modern fonts.
Other examples:

- `lmvtt`: variable width teletype font of Latin Modern fonts
- `qcr`: TeX Gyre Cursor (similar to Courier)

Manually the font family for `\ttfamily` can be redefined, e.g.:

```
\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{qcr}
```

Often there are font packages that take care of this and some other things. For example, TeX Gyre Cursor can be enabled by package `tgcursor`:

```
\usepackage{tgcursor}
```

Users of XeTeX and LuaTeX that support Unicode and OpenType fonts can use package `fontspec` and its possibilities to define and setup teletype fonts (e.g. `\setmonofont`).

Answer (score 9):

```
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
```

for instance, will set the default monospaced font to Adobe Courier. You need to give the Karl Berry's name of the font, provided it has been prepared for use with latex.

This [link](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html) gives  a list of tt fonts prepared for use with LaTeX. If you want to use a font that is not prepared for LaTeX, you will have to do the job yourself, for example with `fontinst`.