# Changing the font size only of the teletype family in a document?

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I have seen [Change \ttfamily font for entire document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158540/change-ttfamily-font-for-entire-document), and this is sort of a follow up to this.

I'd like to use a "palatino" like font (`tgpagella`) - but I'd also like to use `{lmodern}`'s `lmtt` as the teletype (typewriter) font. Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}            % have lmtt loaded; but...
\usepackage{tgpagella}          % use "palatino" as main font, ...
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt} % and use lmtt for teletype family

\begin{document}
testing %
\makeatletter % must be wrapping outside the \texttt; not just the \typeout inside the \texttt !
\texttt{testing %
  \typeout{ttdefault is \ttdefault, \f@size ; \meaning\f@size} %
}
\makeatother %
t\texttt{t}e\texttt{e}s\texttt{s}t\texttt{t}i\texttt{i}n\texttt{n}g\texttt{g}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image: test.png]

... and it should be visible that `lmtt` teletype is just slightly smaller than the `tgpagella` roman. Correspondingly, I'd like to increase just the size of the teletype font; which by the `\typeout` of `\f@size`, I gather, is:

```
ttdefault is lmtt, 10; macro:->10
```

... the same as the one, set in the `\documentclass`.

So my questions are:

- Am I reading (or rather, `\typeout`-ing) the current font size of the teletype font correctly (i.e. is just the `\f@size` inside `\texttt` enough)?
- How can I change just the size of the teletype font document-wide?

Comment: `\usepackage{etoolbox} \appto\ttfamily{\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont}`?

Comment: Thanks for that, @Manuel - so I should basically redefine `\ttfamily`? That seems to work for me, except `\fontsize{10.5pt}{12.0pt}` seems to be good enough for me (I printed the default the `\f@baselineskip` to get at the "12.0pt"; not sure if this is correct either). Feel free to post this as an asnwer - cheers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may scale up Latin Modern Mono or down TeX Gyre Pagella. The latter is easier, because `tgpagella` accepts a `scale` option.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.95877]{tgpagella} % use "palatino" as main font, ...
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}       % and use lmtt for teletype family

\begin{document}
testing %
t\texttt{t}e\texttt{e}s\texttt{s}t\texttt{t}i\texttt{i}n\texttt{n}g\texttt{g}

\sbox0{e}\the\ht0

\sbox0{\ttfamily e}\the\ht0

\end{document}
```

As you see, the height of `e` is the same in the text font and in the mono font. The shapes are not the same (Palatino has quite wide overshoot), but you get the idea.

[image]

How did I determine the scaling factor? Trial and error.

Comment: Thanks for that @egreg - but there may be a case where I've "inherited" the roman font properties from an extern document class (so I wouldn't want to scale the roman font); there may be a case where I'm using fonts where neither the roman nor the monospaced fonts support a `scale` option. How would one proceed in that case - should `\appto\ttfamily...` as in Manuel's comment be used?

Comment: @sdaau No easy solution for that; you have to copy the `t1lmtt.fd` file adding a scale factor. The `\appto` strategy can't work. I'd probably use a different monospaced font, the serifs of `lmtt` don't go along with those of Palatino.

Comment: Thanks @egreg - can you please just note one example pitfall with the `\appto` strategy as a reminder ( otherwise I might feel compelled to try it at a later date, should I bump into the same with different fonts `:)` ) Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau If you do `\xapptocmd{\ttfamily}{\fontsize{10.5}{12}\selectfont}` as suggested (with `xpatch`), the font will be wrong when `\ttfamily` is used at a different size (say in footnotes or in section titles).

Answer (score 8):

Since the `TeX Gyre Pagella` and `Latin Modern` font families are both available in Opentype format (and, incidentally, are produced by the same digital foundry), you may want to consider switching to either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and using the `fontspec` package to load the fonts. The `fontspec` package provides the option `Scale=MatchLowercase` to automate the process of scaling fonts.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Latin Modern Mono}  % equate the x-heights of the fonts
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\begin{document}
testing 
\texttt{testing}
t\texttt{t}e\texttt{e}s\texttt{s}t\texttt{t}i\texttt{i}n\texttt{n}g\texttt{g}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

If @mico recommend you to switch to XeLaTeX then I can recommend you to switch to plain TeX and OPmac. Example:

```
\input opmac
\input cs-pagella

normal: t{\tt t}e{\tt e}s{\tt s}t{\tt t}i{\tt i}n{\tt n}g{\tt g}

\def\tt{\tentt\thefontscale[1050]} % correction of \tt font

corrected: t{\tt t}e{\tt e}s{\tt s}t{\tt t}i{\tt i}n{\tt n}g{\tt g}

\typosize[12/14] % the correction is valid for all sizes

corrected: t{\tt t}e{\tt e}s{\tt s}t{\tt t}i{\tt i}n{\tt n}g{\tt g}

\bye!
```

[image: ttcorr]

Comment: I like your recommendation/s. It is good to have a strong advocate of plain tex in the site. +1.

Comment: Thanks @wipet - I had no idea it would look so relatively easy to do in plain tex - cheers!